# How to substring in visual basic

Tags: substring

hi im trying to get the user to input their full name , and taking that input as a string . so im trying to use substring to remove the surname for my need but i cant seem to do it correctly . this is my code

```
    Dim name As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim findSpace As String
    Dim begin As Integer = 0
    Dim temp As Integer = 0

    Do Until (findSpace = " ")

        temp = (begin + 1)
        findSpace = (name.Substring(begin, temp))

        begin = begin + 1
    Loop

    Dim surname As String = name.Substring(begin, name.Length - 1)
    Dim initial As String = name.Substring(0, 1)

    ListBox1.Items.Add(surname + initial)
```

the actual output required is :: Surname of employee followed by a space and the employee’s firstname initial

and i cant seem to get it.
any help will be mean so much
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure a loop is necessary in this case!

```
Dim name As String = TextBox1.Text
Dim nameArray as String() = name.split(" ")
Dim fullName as string = nameArray(1) & " " & nameArray(0).Substring(0,1)

ListBox1.Items.Add(fullName)
```

John Smith would output as `Smith J`

Comment: Not a problem, make sure to mark it as accepted :) Also, please note that this will only work assuming the name has a first name and a last name. A value of just `John` would throw an error.

Comment: definitely will do :-).